# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'. for big frames

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, python-3.6

this is my code. and i don't know what is the problem. the my goal is read more number frames and then convert them to array and finally split them to train and test data.

```
def read_frames(PATH, num1, num2,seq_len,count,num):
    directory = os.listdir(PATH)
    
    for i in range(num1,num2):
        source_folder = PATH + '/' +'{}'.format(directory[i])
        print("appending the images is started for:", directory[i])
        for item in sorted(os.listdir(source_folder), key = len):
            img = Image.open(os.path.join(source_folder, item))
            frames.append(item)
            x.append(np.asarray(img))
            count+=1
            if count == seq_len:
                break
```

this is a function that read the frames from the path and convert them to array. seq_len is the number of frames.i read the frames in 3 parts. 2 parts using the function that mentioned and other part is:

```
seq_len = 1624
frames = []
x = []
y = []
w=[]
count = 0
num = 0
PATH = ""
directory = os.listdir(PATH)
print("#.................reading and appending the frames for PART1 are started...........#","\n")
for i in range(0, len(directory)):
    source_folder = "PATH/{}".format(directory[i])
    print(num)
    # print(source_folder)
    print("appending the images is started for:", directory[i])
    for item in sorted(os.listdir(source_folder), key = len):
        # print(item)
        # print(count)
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(source_folder, item))
        frames.append(item)
        x.append(np.asarray(img))
        count+=1
        if count == seq_len:
            break
```

the total number of frames that reading from 3 parts are 333060.
when running this cell:

```
w = np.array(x)
print('w_shape: ', np.array(w, dtype='uint8').shape)
```

i expected that the output be (333060,224,224,3) but it is not. and i face this error.

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

when the number of frames are not more this error doesn't happening and when the number of frames are more i face with that error. i using this frames for my pre-trained cnn + lstm network.
please help me to solve that.

Comment: What is `w.dtype`?  (without the `uint8` change)

Comment: the python said that is object. but when i print(w) , all of are matrix with numbers.

Comment: the output of print(w) is: 
[array([[[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [3, 1, 4],
        ...,
        [0, 2, 1],
        [0, 2, 1],
        [1, 3, 2]],

       [[0, 4, 3],
        [0, 2, 1],
        [2, 0, 3],
        ...,
        
       ...
        [0, 0, 0],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 4],
        [1, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 1],
        ...,
        [2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]], dtype=uint8)

i dont know what happening...

Comment: Doesn't `w = np.array(x)` give a `ragged array` warning?  When the code works all items in `x` match in size.  But the larger case must include one or more elements that differ.  I suspect `w.shape` changes significantly when in the error siguation.

Comment: how can i solve it?

Comment: Identify the problem array, the new one that's different.  **I do not have your data**